# How are the Bell states entangled

Tags: entanglement, bell-basis

I've been trying to follow Qiskit Global Summer School 2020 and understood that if a pure state $S$ on systems $A$ and $B$ cannot be written as a tensor product of some state from $A$ and some state from $B$ then it is correlated and therefore entangled.

The thing is that on the same slide, the instructor shares a general formula of the Bell states that represents it as a tensor product which was very conflicting.

Course link: https://youtu.be/9MpSQglnqI0?t=327 minute 5:27

[image: Course slide capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term
$$(\mathbb{I} \otimes \sigma_{x}^j\sigma_{z}^i)|\psi^{00}\rangle$$
is the state $|\psi^{00}\rangle$ multiplied by $(\mathbb{I} \otimes \sigma_{x}^j\sigma_{z}^i)$. So, the formula doesn't represent $|\psi^{ij}\rangle$ as a tensor product. It shows how to get any of the four entangled forms starting from $|\psi^{00}\rangle$ by applying local operations.

Comment: mmhhmmm, does it mean that i can't distribute over ket with the tensor product to obtain  

|00⟩ ⊗ () |00⟩ and |00⟩ is system A and () |00⟩ is system B?

Comment: @Tawfik $|\psi^{00}\rangle$ is already a two qubit entangled state

Comment: ah that's true!